# Rearranging arrays to their original order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Suppose I have an array and to find the minimum value I use Arrays.sort() function but if I want to get arrays in the original order which function should I use?

Comment: Make a copy of the array before calling sort

Comment: You can't use a function for that. Once the order is changed, you cannot restore it. Create a copy of the array before sorting it and only sort one of the two copies.

Comment: You can find the minimum value of an array without sorting it. Finding the minimum is O(n), much better than sorting.

Comment: Finding minimum can be done in `O(n)` time and in case if you are working with range queries, Use `SegmentTree` to answer the queries in `O(log n)` time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the array unchanged and look through it to find the minimum value.  Here is some pseudocode:

```
method findMin(theArray)
  minVal <- theArray[0]
  for (i in 1 to (theArray.size - 1))
    if (minVal > theArray[i])
      minVal <- theArray[i]
    endif
  endfor
  return minVal
endmethod
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] myList = {2,1,4,3,5};
int[] copyList = Arrays.copyOf(myList, 5);
Arrays.sort(copyList);
```

Copy your current list to another list.
Sort the copied list for your result.
Your original list remains unchanged